# Custom scope with koin and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope, android-koin

I must use Koin to construct a custom scope using "Android Service" in my Android app module. I read other blogs and the Koin documentation; a few of them are below.

1. [Understanding Android Scopes with Koin](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-android-scopes-with-koin-cfe6b60ca579)
2. [Android Sample project](https://github.com/kmshack/example-koin-android-scope)
3. [Koin Scope documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/scopes)

Any suggestions appreciated